# How to listen to an existing queue in Spring AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a remote RabbitMQ server which has some queues I want to listen to. I tried this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queueName")
public void receive(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

But it tried to create a new queue. Result is predictable - access denied.

```
o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: queueName
```

I didn't declare any queue in any other way.

How can I listen to an existing queue on a remote server? Also, is there a way to check if this queue exists? And I saw this line

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{autoDeleteQueue2.name}")
```

in a tutorial. What does `#{queueName.name}` mean?

Logs and the beginning of the stack trace:

```
2018-08-30 22:10:21.968  WARN 12124 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: queueName
2018-08-30 22:10:21.991  WARN 12124 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=3

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[queueName]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:711) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:588) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:996) [spring-rabbit-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Comment: You can declare a value in the application.properties like my.awesome.queue=awesome.queue and then use it in the bean @RabbitListener(queues= "${my.awesome.queue}). If you are using spring-boot you could check this out -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html.

Comment: Refer Tutorial 6 for Remote Queue Listener https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/spring-amqp

To use to a remote RabbitMQ installation set the following properties:
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: <rabbitmq-server>
    username: <tutorial-user>
    password: <tutorial-user>

Comment: Would you mind to show more logs on the matter? There should be something like `Queue declaration failed; retries left=` with the stack trace for the reason of the `this.channel.queueDeclarePassive(queueName)` failure.

Comment: `o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: queueName` simply means the queue doesn't exist. See my answer.

Comment: Snehal Patel, I established the properties. Btw, it required SSL permission

Comment: Do you able to create queue manually from rabbit admin dashboard? Adding a consumer to existing queue could be cause to loss messages for other consumers if your consumer does a different task. Creating a seperate queue and binding it to existing exchange is more elegent solution if your consumer does another task.

Comment: I can't create anything. Only consume and produce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you don't have configuration permission on the broker, the `queueDeclarePassive` used by the listener is allowed (it checks for the presence of the queue).

> o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue: queueName

That just means that the queue doesn't exist.

> `@RabbitListener(queues = "#{autoDeleteQueue2.name}")`

That is used to get the queue name at runtime (when you have permission to create queues).

e.g.

```
@Bean
public AnonymousQueue autoDeleteQueue2() {
    return new AnonymousQueue();
}
```

Spring will add that queue to the broker with a random, unique name. The listener is then configured with the actual queue name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to listen to a queue with rabbitMq :

```
@Component
public class RabbitConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @RabbitListener(bindings =
    @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = "${queue.topic}", durable = "true"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = "${queue.exchange}", type = ExchangeTypes.FANOUT, durable = "true")
    )
    )
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And the config (application.yaml) :

```
queue:
  topic: mytopic
  exchange: myexchange
```

In rabbitmq, consumer are associated with exchanges. It allow you to define how the messages must be consumed (are all consumer listen to all message ? Is this enought if only one consumer read the message ? ...)

Comment: That configuration (`@QueueBinding`) will attempt to declare the queue, which is exactly what he doesn't want to do because he doesn't have permissions.

Comment: If the queue is already declared, it won't recreate it. But I think declaring the exchange is mandatory.

Comment: No; generally consumers don't know about exchanges; it's provided in the `@QueueBinding` as a convenience so all the configuration is in one place. Consumers only know about queues; if the queue exists it will be bound to (at least) the default exchange (`""`), And he doesn't have permissions to create queues `But it tried to create a new queue. Result is predictable - access denied.`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to listen to a specific 'queue' using Spring Integration:

**SpringIntegrationConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringIntegrationConfiguration {

@Value("${rabbitmq.queueName}")
private String queueName;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ampqInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, queueName))
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
  }
}
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

@Value("${rabbitmq.topicExchangeName}")
private String topicExchangeName;

@Value("${rabbitmq.queueName}")
private String queueName;

@Value("${rabbitmq.routingKey}")
private String routingKey;

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey);
  }

}
```

**Application.yml**

```
rabbitmq:
topicExchangeName: spring-boot-exchange
queueName: spring-boot
routingKey: foo.bar.#
```